# 'Expected 2 or more dimensions (got 1)' in PyTorch NLLloss even though tensors are of right dimension

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to create a simple neural network with 2 inputs and 2 outputs, based on a mathematical function I created.

My problem is that I am unable to compute the loss.

X_s is a (600,2) array and F is the resulting array from my function (code not shown) of size (600,2). Here is the model:

```
class ReactorNet(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, input_size, hidden1_size, hidden2_size, num_classes):

      super(ReactorNet, self).__init__()
      self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden1_size)
      self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
      self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden1_size, hidden2_size)
      self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
      self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden2_size, num_classes)

  def forward(self, x):
      out = self.fc1(x)
      
      out = self.relu1(out)
      out = self.fc2(out)
      out = self.relu2(out)
      out = self.fc3(out)
      return out

model = ReactorNet(2, 10, 4, 2 )
print(model)

X = torch.rand((1,2))
X = X.view(-1, 2)
output = model(X)

from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as func

tensor_x = torch.Tensor(X_s) # transform to torch tensor
tensor_y = torch.Tensor(F)

my_dataset = TensorDataset(tensor_x,tensor_y) # create your datset
print(my_dataset)
train_set, val_set = torch.utils.data.random_split(my_dataset, [550, 50])

learn_rate = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
epochs = 1

for i in range(epochs):
    for data in train_set:
        input, output = data
        print(input)
        print(output)   
        model.zero_grad()
        result = model(input.view(-1,2).data)
        result = result.data
        result = result.squeeze(0)
        print(result)
        loss = func.nll_loss(output, result)
        loss.backward()
        learn_rate.step()
    print(loss)


# Test the network
model.eval()
```

The resulting error occurs on the NLL loss line:
`Expected 2 or more dimensions (got 1)`. Printing the tensors show that they seem to be of the right dimensions.

```
tensor([0.7197, 0.0468])
tensor([0.3284, 0.2165])
tensor([-0.0252, -0.2400])
```

Comment: Those are not 2-dimensional tensors.  Those are one-dimensional tensors with two elements.

Comment: Noted. I have changed my input/output arrays to dimensions (600,2,1) and then converted them to tensors. Running the code gives me another error on the same line - `expected scalar type Long but found Float`. My data is the form of floats of numbers less than 1. Changing the type to long tensor makes all my data points equal to 0. What do you recommend I do?

Comment: Sorry, for my denseness, but WHICH line gets the error?  Where is the "NLL loss line"?

Comment: Always post the complete traceback.

Comment: Apologies.  `loss = func.nll_loss(output, result)` results in the error `expected scalar type Long but found Float`. Considering all my data points are numbers normalised between 0 and 1, I think I read somewhere NLL loss is unsuitable for this case.